# Video is not playing on any of browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, opera, webm

When I am trying to open Google [Material Design Spec](http://www.google.com.ua/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight) and click on `play` button nothing happens. Checked on Chrome, Opera, Firefox.

[image]

When I am trying to open video url directly, first time - it doesn't load ether, but second time it load's successfully. Very weird.

[image]

I tried to clean cache - nothing. Any suggestions how to fix this issue?

Comment: This is `*.webm`

Comment: I should add.  I was unable to play the videos either ( on that website ) other webm videos I had no problem playing.